# Touch detection without event processing

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos2d.  I would like to be able to detect whether the screen is touched at a particular instant - that is, rather than intercepting an event when it occurs, I want to detect the presence of touch at a particular moment.

The reason is that I am animating sprites and want to determine if the sprite should keep moving - if the screen is still touched.  I cannot use ccTouchesEnded because each time an animation starts I set isTouchEnabled to false because I also want the user to be able to tap rapidly on the screen to move the sprite but if they tapped too rapidly, it would mess with the position of the sprite during the animation process - which I have found screws up the positions of my objects in weird ways.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be any public API to detect touches other than enabling and receiving these events in the main UI run loop.

You can keep handling events, and set the state left by the last touch event in a model object or global variables.  Then you can poll your app's own internal state at any time.

Instead of disabling touches, you can just have your touch handler not do inappropriate things if the event time stamp is too close to some animation start time.

Comment: I've tried using timers to handle the synchronization of the animations but I have found it impossible to get the timing exactly right.  I've also used a couple of global variables for "processing" and "animating" where I tell the touch handler not to act if processing (repeated touches) or animating (touch and hold) but somehow it doesn't seem to quite work.  I will look more carefully at that logic and post another question.  Thank you.